# Full screen nested Navigation Controller

Tags: swift

I want to have an intro screen, and only then traverse to a navigation controller.

It seems like whatever segue I pick the navigation controller doesn't cover the whole screen, and rather is presented modally.

How can I get it to cover the whole screen?

[image]

Comment: Your first ViewController is not embedded in any navigation controller, how can you push a navigation controller on top of it? Embed your first ViewController inside a UINavigationController

Comment: Because you place a navigation controller on the stack? Like you might place a UINavigationController inside a tabbarcontroller. So the answer is, you can always do that, if you choose.

Answer (score 2):

Select the first segue to navigation controller and choose **present modally** and **Full Screen** options from IB inspector on left side like shown in image below

[image]

Comment: Which Xcode version is this? I'm on 12.2 and don't see this.

Comment: select the segue of first controller then it will appear. @WishIHadThreeGuns

Comment: Yes, not in 12.2 it doesn't. It works in 12.4.

Comment: please mark my answer correct if it solved your problem

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, as in the comment above the one where you asked if it solved the problem.